# Scalebox not working properly inside hyperlinks when using ocgx2 package

Tags: hyperref, ocg, hyperlink, scalebox, ocgx2

I am using hyperlink text formatted with `graphicx`' `\scalebox` command with independent factors for horizontal and vertical scaling. When formatting is applied inside `hyperref`'s hyperlinks, the text in resulting PDF is still present in the PDF (may be copied), but became invisible (and also cause further problems when other packages are added that would use such solution).

The obvious workaround would be to switch to hyperlink used inside formatting command. Unfortunately, in actual document `\hyperlink`s are generated by other package that forces internal formatting (as described in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443962/33249) answer to the original question that led to identifying the problem). Then, `relsize`'s `\textscale` command is an alternative, but it does not allow for independent scaling in both dimensions, so it cannot fully relace `\scalebox`.

When `ocgx2` package is not used (or is used without `ocgcolorlinks` option) the internal formatting works properly.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\myfmt}[1]{\scalebox{.8}[.7]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{t1}{Some text}.

\hyperlink{t1}{Unformatted link}.

Desired but not working: \hyperlink{t1}{\myfmt{Formatted (inside) link}}.

Working but not applicable: \myfmt{\hyperlink{t1}{Formatted (outside) link}}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The link is already invisible if one inserts a `\pdfsave/\pdfrestore` pair (`\newcommand{\myfmt}[1]{{#1\pdfsave\pdfrestore}}`). 
Imho this interrupts the path and ocgx can no longer use the text for clipping.  I would drop the idea to use scalebox here and try to implement whatever you want to achieve with proper font commands.

Comment: Further experiments indicate that `\hyperlink` has a problem with graphics in general, not just `\scalebox`.  Even `\fbox{...}` has problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command `\ocglinkprotect{...}` defined by `ocgx2` was provided for such special cases:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\myfmt[1]{\ocglinkprotect{\scalebox{.8}[.7]{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{t1}{Some text}.

\hyperlink{t1}{Unformatted link}.

%%%%%%%%%%%
This works: \hyperlink{t1}{\myfmt{Formatted (inside) link}}.
%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

Other use-cases:

- graphics inside link text:

  ```
  \hyperlink{t1}{Unformatted link text \ocglinkprotect{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}} unformatted link text cont'ed}
  ```
- boxed portions inside link text:

  ```
  \hyperlink{t1}{Unformatted link text \ocglinkprotect{\fbox{f-boxed text}} unformatted link text cont'ed}
  ```

Note that the text argument of `\ocglinkprotect{...}` doesn't wrap around line breaks. But this should not be an issue, as such portions of the link text that need protection (`\scalebox...`, `\fbox{...}`, `\includegraphics{...}` etc.) are not breakable anyway.